# How does the Hip hop virtual machine (HHVM) theoretically improve PHP runtime performance?

Tags: php, performance

From a high level, how does Facebook, et. al use to improve PHP performance with the Hip Hop Virtual Machine?

How does it differ from executing code using the traditional zend engine? Is it because types are optionally defined with hack which allow for pre-optimization techniques?

My curiousity arose after reading this article, [HHVM adoption](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1645476812348639/hhvm-adoption-news/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They replaced TranslatorX64’s tracelets with the new HipHop Intermediate Representation (hhir), and a new indirection layer in which resides the logic to generate hhir, which is actually referred to by the same name, hhir.

From a high level, it is using 6 instructions to do the what required 9 instructions before, as noted here: "It begins with the same typechecks but the body of the translation is 6 instructions, significantly better than the 9 from TranslatorX64"

http://hhvm.com/blog/2027/faster-and-cheaper-the-evolution-of-the-hhvm-jit

> "We solved this problem by adding a new layer of indirection. This new
>   layer is an SSA form intermediate representation, positioned between
>   the bytecodes in TranslatorX64’s tracelets and the x86 machine code we
>   want to end up with. It’s strongly typed and designed to facilitate a
>   number of optimizations we wanted to port from TranslatorX64 as well
>   as new optimizations in the future. This new IR, named hhir (short for
>   HipHop Intermediate Representation), completely replaced TranslatorX64
>   as hhvm’s JIT in May of 2013. While hhir specifically refers to the
>   representation itself, we often use the name to refer to all the
>   pieces of code that interact with it. If you’ve looked at our source
>   code recently you might have noticed that a class named TranslatorX64
>   still exists and contains a nontrivial amount of code. That’s mostly
>   an artifact of how the system is designed and is something we plan to
>   eventually clean up. All of the code left in TranslatorX64 is
>   machinery required to emit code and link translations together; the
>   code that understood how to translate individual bytecodes is gone
>   from TranslatorX64.
>
> When hhir replaced TranslatorX64, it was generating code that was
>   roughly 5% faster and looked significantly better upon manual
>   inspection. We followed up its production debut with another
>   mini-lockdown and got an additional 10% in performance gains on top of
>   that. To see some of these improvements in action, let’s look at a
>   function addPositive and part of its translation.
>
> ```php
> function addPositive($arr) {
>       $n = count($arr);
>       $sum = 0;
>       for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
>         $elem = $arr[$i];
>         if ($elem > 0) {
>           $sum = $sum + $elem;
>         }
>       }
>       return $sum;
>     }
> ```
>
> This function looks like a lot of PHP code: it loops over an array and
>   does something with each element. Let’s focus on lines 5 and 6 for
>   now, along with their bytecode:
>
> ```
>     $elem = $arr[$i];
>     if ($elem > 0) {
>   // line 5
>    85: CGetM <L:0 EL:3>
>    98: SetL 4
>   100: PopC
>   // line 6
>   101: Int 0
>   110: CGetL2 4
>   112: Gt
>   113: JmpZ 13 (126)
> ```
>
> These two lines load an element from an array, store it in a local
>   variable, then compare the value of that local with 0 and
>   conditionally jump somewhere based on the result. If you’re interested
>   in more detail about what’s going on in the bytecode, you can skim
>   through bytecode.specification. The JIT, both now and back in the
>   TranslatorX64 days, breaks this code up into two tracelets: one with
>   just the CGetM, then another with the rest of the instructions (a full
>   explanation of why this happens isn’t relevant here, but it’s mostly
>   because we don’t know at compile time what the type of the array
>   element will be). The translation of the CGetM boils down to a call to
>   a C++ helper function and isn’t very interesting, so we’ll be looking
>   at the second tracelet. This commit was TranslatorX64’s official
>   retirement, so let’s use its parent to see how TranslatorX64
>   translated this code.
>
> ```
>   cmpl  $0xa, 0xc(%rbx)
>   jnz 0x276004b2
>   cmpl  $0xc, -0x44(%rbp)
>   jnle 0x276004b2
> 101: SetL 4
> 103: PopC
>   movq  (%rbx), %rax
>   movq  -0x50(%rbp), %r13
> 104: Int 0
>   xor %ecx, %ecx
> 113: CGetL2 4
>   mov %rax, %rdx
>   movl  $0xa, -0x44(%rbp)
>   movq  %rax, -0x50(%rbp)
>   add $0x10, %rbx    
>   cmp %rcx, %rdx    
> 115: Gt
> 116: JmpZ 13 (129)
>   jle 0x7608200
> ```
>
> The first four lines are typechecks verifying that the value in $elem
>   and the value on the top of the stack are the types we expect. If
>   either of them fails, we’ll jump to code that triggers a retranslation
>   of the tracelet, using the new types to generate a differently
>   specialized chunk of machine code. The meat of the translation
>   follows, and the code has plenty of room for improvement. There’s a
>   dead load on line 8, an easily avoidable register to register move on
>   line 12, and an opportunity for constant propagation between lines 10
>   and 16. These are all consequences of the bytecode-at-a-time approach
>   used by TranslatorX64. No respectable compiler would ever emit code
>   like this, but the simple optimizations required to avoid it just
>   don’t fit into the TranslatorX64 model.
>
> Now let’s see the same tracelet translated using hhir, at the same
>   hhvm revision:
>
> ```
>   cmpl  $0xa, 0xc(%rbx)
>   jnz 0x276004bf
>   cmpl  $0xc, -0x44(%rbp)
>   jnle 0x276004bf
> 101: SetL 4
>   movq  (%rbx), %rcx
>   movl  $0xa, -0x44(%rbp)
>   movq  %rcx, -0x50(%rbp)
> 115: Gt    
> 116: JmpZ 13 (129)
>   add $0x10, %rbx
>   cmp $0x0, %rcx    
>   jle 0x76081c0
> ```
>
> It begins with the same typechecks but the body of the translation is
>   6 instructions, significantly better than the 9 from TranslatorX64.
>   Notice that there are no dead loads or register to register moves, and
>   the immediate 0 from the Int 0 bytecode was propagated down to the cmp
>   on line 12. Here’s the hhir that was generated between the tracelet
>   and that translation:
>
> ```
>   (00) DefLabel    
>   (02) t1:FramePtr = DefFP
>   (03) t2:StkPtr = DefSP<6> t1:FramePtr
>   (05) t3:StkPtr = GuardStk<Int,0> t2:StkPtr
>   (06) GuardLoc<Uncounted,4> t1:FramePtr
>   (11) t4:Int = LdStack<Int,0> t3:StkPtr
>   (13) StLoc<4> t1:FramePtr, t4:Int
>   (27) t10:StkPtr = SpillStack t3:StkPtr, 1
>   (35) SyncABIRegs t1:FramePtr, t10:StkPtr
>   (36) ReqBindJmpLte<129,121> t4:Int, 0
> ```
>
> The bytecode instructions have been broken down into smaller, simpler
>   operations. Many operations hidden in the behavior of certain
>   bytecodes are explicitly represented in hhir, such as the LdStack on
>   line 6 which is part of the SetL. By using unnamed temporaries (t1,
>   t2, etc…) instead of physical registers to represent the flow of
>   values, we can easily track the definition and use(s) of each value.
>   This makes it trivial to see if the destination of a load is actually
>   used, or if one of the inputs to an instruction is really a constant
>   value from 3 bytecodes ago. For a much more thorough explanation of
>   what hhir is and how it works, take a look at ir.specification.
>
> This example showed just a few of the improvements hhir made over
>   TranslatorX64. Getting hhir deployed to production and retiring
>   TranslatorX64 in May 2013 was a great milestone to hit, but it was
>   just the beginning. Since then, we’ve implemented many more
>   optimizations that would be nearly impossible in TranslatorX64, making
>   hhvm almost twice as efficient in the process. It’s also been crucial
>   in our efforts to get hhvm running on ARM processors by isolating and
>   reducing the amount of architecture-specific code we need to
>   reimplement. Watch for an upcoming post devoted to our ARM port for
>   more details!"

Answer (score 1):

In short: they try to minimize random memory access and jumps between pieces of code in memory to play nicely with CPU cache.

According to [HHVM Performance Status](https://code.facebook.com/videos/496451387125899/hhvm-performance-status-hack-dev-day/) they optimized most frequently used data types, which are strings and arrays, to minimize random memory access. The idea is to keep data pieces used together (like items in an array) as close to each other as possible in memory, ideally in a linear fashion. That way, if data fits into CPU L2/L3 cache, it can be processed orders of magnitude faster than if it was in RAM.

Another technique mentioned is compiling most frequently used paths in a code in such a way that compiled version is as linear (e.i. has least amount of "jumps") as possible and loads data in/out of memory as rarely as possible.